# Can i connect to different account AWS services(s3, dynamoDb) from my account ec2 using VPC Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Can i connect to different account AWS services(s3, dynamoDb) from my account ec2 using VPC Endpoint?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking if you can connect your ec2 instance from one account to a resource in another account using a VPC endpoint?

Comment: yes that is my question.

Comment: What is the situation you are trying to solve? There might be a better way to achieve it if can provide more information. Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 and Amazon DynamoDB are accessed on the Internet via API calls.

When a call is made to these services, a set of credentials is provided to identify the account and user.

If you wish to access S3 or DynamoDB resources belonging to a different account, you simply need to use credentials that belong to the target account. The actual request can be made from anywhere on the Internet (eg from Amazon EC2 or from a computer under your desk) — the only things that matters is that you have valid credentials linked to the desired AWS account.

There is no need to manipulate VPC configurations to access resources belonging to a different AWS Account. The source of the request is actually irrelevant.